# Python send @-sign/alt-gr+Q/ALT+64 to putty

Tags: python-3.x, putty, pywin32, win32com, win32gui

If the "ptyFoo" string contains a @-character, the @ will not displayed in the putty session. Also '^%q' doesn't work... Any suggestions?
Terminal-type string is "xterm"

Thx in advance

```html
def sendToPutty():
    handle = win32gui.FindWindow(None,usrPuttyTitle)
    shell = win32com.client.Dispatch("WScript.Shell")
    shell.SendKeys('%')
    win32gui.SetForegroundWindow(handle)
    shell.SendKeys(ptyLockCMD + ptyFoo + '{ENTER}')
```

Answer (score 0):

I will answer myself.
It's now a mixture of pyperclip and pyautogui.

```html
[..]
# copy the content of ptyFoo into the clipboard
pyperclip.copy(ptyFoo)
[..]
def sendToPutty():
    handle = win32gui.FindWindow(None,usrPuttyTitle)
    shell = win32com.client.Dispatch("WScript.Shell")
    shell.SendKeys('%')
    win32gui.SetForegroundWindow(handle)
    # get the coordinates of the putty window
    rect = win32gui.GetWindowRect(handle)
    x = rect[0]
    y = rect[1]
    # move mouse to the window +55px on x,y
    # paste the content from clipboard + enter
    pyautogui.moveTo(x+55,y+55)
    pyautogui.click(button='right')
    pyautogui.press('enter')
```

Works for me and my conditions.